# How are surface roughness specimens created?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, measurements, metrology

I'm wondering how surface roughness specimens that are used to calibrate surface roughness machines are created. Specifically those in the 125-200 µin range. Is this typically done with vertical milling, electroforming, etc?

Here is an example of what I'm referring to: https://www.grainger.com/product/INSIZE-Surface-Roughness-Specimen-463T67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4924890/ indicates that at least some methods used are:

- Chemical etching or oxidation and at the same time states that for 6,
  20, 60, and 200 μm.
- CNC diamond turning for 0.3 to 3um.

100µin = 2.54µm

Skim through the article though... They have µm referencing both Ra values and wavelengths and I am not sure what the difference is so the numbers I posted above might be mixed up between the two.